# Search Dictionary Values in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Having a dictionary like this:

```
ossec_datacenter:
  atlanta:
    hostname: 'server1.fakedomain.net'
    ip: '192.168.12.170'
    port: '1515'
  miami:
    hostname: 'server2.fakedomain.net'
    ip: '192.168.20.31'
    port: '1514'
  dallas:
    hostname: 'server2.fakedomain.net'
    ip: '192.168.20.20'
    port: '1515'
```

How would I search for all values in this dictionary in my `when` clause?

I can access variables using `ossec_datacenter[ossec_dc]['hostname']`

But I want so search all values to make sure no matches are present.

In other words I don't want the `inventory_hostname` nor the IP to be found anywhere in that data structure.

Comment: Edited the question for clarity. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use json_query (requires ansible 2.2) you can do this to search ip and hostname:

```
    - name: find inventory_hostname
      set_fact:
        found: True
      with_items:
        - "{{ ossec_datacenter | json_query('*.ip') }}"
        - "{{ ossec_datacenter | json_query('*.hostname') }}"
      when: "inventory_hostname == item"
```

or if you want to search any of the keys in the datacenters (ip, hostname, or port):

```
- name: find inventory_hostname
  set_fact:
    found: True
  with_items: "{{ ossec_datacenter | json_query('*.*') }}"
  when: "inventory_hostname == item"
```

and then test the `found` var.

Comment: Unrelated, but I needed to grab one value out of a complex JSON structure and then get another value from that same list item, and `json_query()` was the only way I was able to do it without a huge mess of tasks. So thanks! Here are full docs: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter

Answer (score 4):

Here's a condition for hostname:

```
when: inventory_hostname not in (ossec_datacenter.values() | map(attribute='hostname') | list)
```

Use `ansible_default_ipv4.address` or some other fact about IP address and reduce your dict with `map(attribute='ip')` to search for IP addresses.