# In Ansible how do I get values from a dictionary and store them in a fact?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Ansible v2.2.1.0

How do I modify the answer in [Search Dictionary Values in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41581273/search-dictionary-values-in-ansible#) to do this?

I have a dictionary:

```
filenames_for_version:
  1.0:
    file1: "Hello.txt"
    file2: "Goodbye.txt"
  2.0:
    file1: "HelloWorld.txt"
    file2: "GoodbyeWorld.txt"
```

Now I want to write a task that does...

```
- name: Get the corresponding **file1** for the version
  set_fact: f1_4_ver={{ what do I put here??? }}
- name: Get the corresponding **file2** for the version
  set_fact: f2_4_ver={{ what do I put here??? }}
```

I want to be able to pass the version as a CLI parameter when I call my playbook, e.g.,

```
$ ansible-playbook -i "localhost," -c local get_filename_for_version.yml -e "version=1.0"
```

...such that if I pass version=1.0, I get...

```
f1_4_ver=Hello.txt
f2_4_ver=Goodbye.txt
```

...and if I pass version=2.0, I get...

```
f1_4_ver=HelloWorld.txt
f2_4_ver=GoodbyeWorld.txt
```

What code should be in the..

```
{{ what do I put here??? }}
```

...part of my tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for troubles by using dots in variable/key names, but:

```
{{ filenames_for_version[version].file1 }}
{{ filenames_for_version[version].file2 }}
```